# Django custom form - TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, typeerror

When I want to create my own form instead of using Django's default one, I get this error: *TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
I wanted to do it by creating subclass of Django's UserCreationForm. I am very new to Django, so any help will be most appreciated.

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from SmartCookbook.modules.forms import RegisterForm
    

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username,
                                password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('homepageSmartCookbookApp')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'sign/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py** (app)

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepageSmartCookbookApp'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='registerSmartCookbookApp'),
]
```

**forms.py** (where I wanted to create multiple custom forms classes)

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    """Registration form class"""
    username = forms.CharField(forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
                             max_length=64,
                             help_text='Enter a valid email address')
    password1 = forms.CharField(forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password Again'}))

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Note that adding .as_view() to urls.py doesn't help

**Traceback:**

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\vlase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\SmartCook\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('',include('SmartCookbook.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\vlase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\SmartCookbook\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\SmartCookbook\views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from SmartCookbook.modules.forms import RegisterForm
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\SmartCookbook\modules\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "C:\Users\vlase\PycharmProjects\SmartCook\SmartCookbook\modules\forms.py", line 8, in RegisterForm
    username = forms.CharField(forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: welcome to SO, please provide traceback from python interpreter as well

Comment: Please also show the error that the console prints.

Comment: why are you passing the `TextInput` instance into the CharField init ? the CharField accepts only kwargs and none of them should be instance of the TextInput

Comment: @Take_Care_ what should he do ? make a proper answer of the solution please i need it too